# How to deal with searching strings and array of strings in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6, lodash

`_.get(params, "_q")` outputs either string or array of strings.
On my current code, when I type for example "hello, there", it translates to array of strings and as a result is says something like `h.get(...).trim is not a function`.

Pls see my current code below. and what i've tried so far.
Is my tried code good or is there a better way using modern JS?

Note: `_` is from lodash.

**Result of console.log(params) when typing "hello, there"**

```
{
    "_q": [
        "hello",
        " there "
    ]
}
```

**Result of console.log(params) when typing "hello"**

```
{
    "_q": "hello"
}
```

**Result of console.log(params) when typing "hello there"**

```
{
    "_q": "hello there"
}
```

Current code

```
 let where = {};

  if (_.get(params, "_q")) {
    where._q = _.get(params, "_q").trim();
  }
```

**What fix I have tried so far**

```
  const _q = _.get(params, "_q");
  if (_q) {
    where._q = []
      .concat(_q)
      .map((str) => str.split(",").map((str) => str.trim()))
      .flat();
  }
```

Comment: `lodash.get({_q: 'hello, there'}, '_q')` returns a string `"hello, there"`, not an array. https://runkit.com/embed/5gpphlg8c9d2 Can't reproduce your issue. So please clarify the input and output

Comment: @PeterSeliger The "What fix I have tried so far" in my question works but not sure if that is the ideal way to do it

Comment: @LinDu.  I have updated my question with some examples

Comment: Is this an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? The title appears to be about searching strings (*or arrays of strings*), but the body content looks to be about Lodash functionality. What are you *really* trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @DrewReese. The result is either strings or array of strings. With my current code, when the output is array of strings, this issues occurs h.get(...).trim is not a function

Comment: Sorry, *what* result is either strings or array of strings? The `_.get(params, "_q")`? What are you expecting? Again, it will probably be easier to help you if we understand what you are trying to do. Can you [edit] to include a better [mcve]?

Comment: I also can't reproduce the issue you describe based on current information. https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-deal-with-searching-strings-and-array-of-strings-in-js-j9vjcm The result is the string `"hello, there"`.

Comment: @DrewReese. Here it is. I've commented out the other result. So the result is either its a string or array of strings.  When its an array of string, I'm getting error of `trim is not a function`... I should be able to cater both. Better if it won't crash if its null or undefined. https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-deal-with-searching-strings-and-array-of-strings-in-js-forked-ylsf8t?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, the "input", e.g. the `"_q"` property value can be either a single string, or an array of strings.

I'd suggest plopping `params._q` into an array and flatten it first, *then* map the strings in the array to a new array of trimmed string values.

Example:

```js
[get(params, "_q")].flat().map((el) => el.trim())
```

Given:

- Array of strings

  ```js
  const params = {
    _q: ["hello", " there "]
  };
  ```

  ```js
  [get(params, "_q")]       // [["hello", " there "]]
    .flat()                 // ["hello", " there "]
    .map((el) => el.trim()) // ["hello", "there"]
  ```
- String

  ```js
  const params = {
    _q: " hello there "
  };
  ```

  ```js
  [get(params, "_q")]       // [" hello there "]
    .flat()                 // [" hello there "]
    .map((el) => el.trim()) // ["hello there"]
  ```

### Demo

```js
const params = {
  _q: ["hello", " there "]
};

console.log([params._q].flat().map((el) => el.trim())); // ["hello", "there"]
```

Comment: Hi Drew. How can I output this as a string always instead of array?

Comment: @Joseph You can [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array which returns a string.

Comment: @Joseph What exactly are you trying to do now? You want your function to always result in a string instead of an array? Even if the input is an array of strings, you want them all trimmed and then "joined" altogether as a single string?